# Stacked area chart with many variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm trying to represent different components of income with stacked areas. My problem is that the my variables aren't stacked at the end :

[image]

Here is my code :

```
p3 <- ggplot(bdd, aes(x, y1))+
geom_area(aes(fill=y1))+
geom_area(data=bdd,aes(x, y2, fill=y2))+
geom_area(data=bdd,aes(x, y3, fill=y3))+
geom_area(data=bdd,aes(x,y4, fill=y4))+
geom_line(data=bdd,aes(x, y5, color="red"))+
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white",colour =  "white",size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.25, linetype = 'solid',colour = "grey"), 
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
scale_fill_manual(values = wes_palette(n=5, name="Moonrise3"))

print(p3)
```

I think the problem comes from the structure of my data, since I have one column for each component of total income I'm trying to represent.

[EDIT] Sample of my data :

```
x <- c(0,37,74,111,148,185,222,259,269,333,370,407,444,481,518,555,592,629,666,703)
y1 <- c(762,780,798,816,834,852,870,887,905,923,941,959,977,995,1013,1024,1032,1010,1017,1024)
y2 <- c(rep(272,15),265,255,245,235,225)
y3 <- c(477,448,420,391,363,334,305,277,248,219,191,162,133,105,76,47,19,0,0,0)
y4 <- c(rep(13,17),0,0,0)

bdd <- data.frame(x,y1,y2,y3,y4)
```

y1 is supposed to be the "final" income, and y2 y3 y4 different amounts composing it.

Thanks for your help,

Chloé

Comment: It would help to have some example data

Comment: does it have to be a ggplot?

Comment: @PorkChop not necessarily.

Comment: Please provide same data, edit question and add the output of `dput(bdd)`. If you work with confidential data then simulate one!

Comment: @aocall the problem is that I work with confidential data. I'll try to give you an example

Comment: Ok, you can find a sample of my data in my post.

Comment: Your example still does not run. Generating your example data and then running the plot leads to `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'y5' not found`. If I then generate a `y5` object, and re-run the plot command, I get `Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale`. If I remove the `scale_fill_manual` call, and re-run the plot, I get `Error in f(...) : Aesthetics can not vary with a ribbon`! Please post a working reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also having difficulty running your function but may have a more general solution.

```
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)

melted <- melt(data = bdd, id = "x", variable.name = "Type", value.name = "Value")

ggplot(melted, aes(x, y = Value, fill = Type)) + geom_area() +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white",colour =  "white",size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"),
          panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.25, linetype = 'solid',colour = "grey"), 
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Plotting multiple `geom_whatever()` layers is fine for some types of data such as `geom_density`, `geom_line` or `geom_point`.  But for area plots, barplots, etc, you need to assign fill to a categorical variable.